# Overriding or shadowing `File` in Typescript

Tags: typescript, overriding, shadow, typescript2.4

I'm using typescript to write extension scripts for a program that has some objects, like File and Text, that duplicate definitions in lib.d.ts.

As a result, a definition like

```
declare File(x: string): object;
```

will cause a duplicate identifier error. Is there a way to selectively override or shadow the library definitions or otherwise replace them with my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to selectively override or shadow the library definitions or otherwise replace them with my own?

Two options:

## Use your own lib

- using the `nolib` tsconfig option and adding your lib to your src.

## Don't use globals

E.g. don't call your variable `File` or `window` or `document` or `location` or other known globals e.g. in node `process` or `global`

## Preference

The second option is ofcourse preferred. Its the cost of working with JavaScript.